# python glib main loop: delaying until loop is entered

Tags: python, glib

Is there a way to schedule the execution of a callable until the glib main loop is entered?

Alternatively, is there a signal I can subscribe to that will indicate that the main loop is entered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [gobject.idle_add](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/gobject-functions.html#function-gobject--idle-add) which will schedule a callable to be executed when the main loop is idle. [gobject.timeout_add](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/gobject-functions.html#function-gobject--timeout-add) is an alternative which uses a timer.

Mind that the callable will be called again and again, unless is returns `False` (or anything that resolves to `False`, like `None`).

Comment: The trick with "timeout_add, return False" serves as a good "one-shot callable", exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Returning no value at all would work, too, because Python functions automatically return `None`. But better do it explicitly...